# Find unique elements in the first list from two lists in Java

Tags: java, list

I am trying to find unique elements in a main list by comparing it with another list with a time complexity better than O(mn). 
Ex:-

`listA, listB . I want to get unique elements only in listA and add to a new list.`

Here is what I did

```
for (String item : listA) {
 if (!listB.contains(item)) {
   newList.add(item)
 }
}
```

Here the time complexity is O(mn). Can anyone help me get to a better solution?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Faster algorithm to find unique element between two arrays?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19203868/faster-algorithm-to-find-unique-element-between-two-arrays)

Comment: Copy `listB` into a `HashSet` and do `setB.contains(item)`, then it is `O(m + n)`.

Comment: TC for HashSet.contains is O(1). Then how is tc for the code O(m+n) ?

Comment: @Newbie Copying `listB` to `setB` is O(m). Iterating over `listA` is O(n).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Set<String> setB = new HashSet<>(listB);
for (String item : listA) {
 if (!setB.contains(item)) {
    newList.add(item);
 }
}
```

Like @Andy Turner suggested. 
Here , Set.contains Time Complexity is O(1).